# Grunt copy files and folders

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I'm using grunt to copy some files, I have this entry that copies fonts:

```
copy: {
        copyFonts: {
            files: [
                {
                    expand: true,
                    src: ['src/theme/type/**'],
                    dest: 'output/css/type/',
                    filter: 'isFile',
                    flatten: true
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

This was working fine, however recently I had to have fonts in separate folders but this command "flattens" the structure. Now simple setting `flatten` to `false` doesn't work. As it then creates all folders from the root and copies them into the destination folder.

e.g.

`src/theme/type/font1` will be copied into

`output/css/type/src/theme/type/font1`

and I want

`output/css/type/font1`

How to change it that it only takes the folders (and content) from within the `type` folder and copies across to destination?